# Testing a portal partly in Silverlight and partly in AngularJS

Tags: silverlight, telerik, protractor

I am testing a portal which is being ported from Silverlight to HTML5(AngularJS).

I am trying to find out the best way to run the tests that cover partly Telerik tests(for SilverLight) and partly Protractor tests(for AngularJS).

Any inputs will be of great help

Thanks,
Sakshi

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - do you mean writing unit tests that run on both - an angular application and on a Silverlight application? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Not Unit tests but End-to-end tests